# PSQLException on \copy query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute \copy query using java (f is a bytea object in test_pdf table) :

```
String sql = "\\copy (SELECT encode(f, 'hex') FROM test_pdf where id='2' LIMIT 1) TO '/home/sourabh/image.hex'";
System.out.println(sql);
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

It gives error :

> \copy (SELECT encode(f, 'hex') FROM test_pdf where id='2' LIMIT 1) TO '/home/sourabh/image.hex'
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"

But when executed on terminal using "psql" gives proper output, i.e., file gets copied to image.hex as expected. Can anybody explain how is syntax error possible when it is syntactically correct.

Comment: `\copy` is a **psql** command and can't be used from within JDBC. To achieve the same thing you need to use the `CopyManager` API: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That should be an answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you.